# Binding literal list to SQL query as column that would return 1 row?

Tags: arrays, t-sql, list

I have an SQL query that returns a single row, I have a list of numbers that I need to have returned as individual rows with the single row data bound to their row.

for example here's what I'm trying to do

```
select a,b,c, barcode
from database
join ('12345', '67890',...) as barcode
where a=1 and b=2 and c=3
```

I need to do it this way due to the fact i'm modifying some code that's looking for a specific format to come from the query, and modifying the code to match the literal list I have is far more difficult than doing something like this

```
    Example Output:

a     b     c     barcode
-     -     -     -------
1     2     3     12345
1     2     3     67890
1     2     3     ....
1     2     3     ....
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method would be to create a barcode table with a single column, insert the values you want here one at a time, then join to that table.

Could use a union to fudge it as well.   Problem with join ('484','48583',...) is you are joining to a single row with multi columns, when you want one row per record.

pseudo coded:

```
select a,b,c, barcode
from database
join (select 12345 union all select 289384 union all...)a as barcode
where a=1 and b=2 and c=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could pass the list as a single CSV string and transform it into a row set of items. A table-valued function is often used in such cases, but there are actually many options to explore. A very comprehensive collection of various methods and their tests can be found in the set of articles by Erland Sommarskog: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

If it was e.g. a function, your query might look like this:

```
SELECT
  t.a,
  t.b,
  t.c,
  s.Value AS barcode
FROM yourtable t
CROSS JOIN dbo.Split('12345,67890', ',') s
WHERE t.a = 1
  AND t.b = 2
  AND t.c = 3
```